# Selenium: Get the URL that Javascript codes redircted to without changing current page

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the URL I am re-directed to when I click one button on the website, and still stay on the same page instead of being redirected. The button is not a simple hyperlink and will trigger a complex Javascript function.

#### click() does not work for me

I refer to [Selenium get URL of "a" Tag without href attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74396709/selenium-get-url-of-a-tag-without-href-attribute/74401877#74401877) and [Selenium: Getting ultimate href/link without clicking on it when it's a javascript call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588021/selenium-getting-ultimate-href-link-without-clicking-on-it-when-its-a-javascri), which shows that the button has to be clicked to get the URL. Of course, I can click() the button and use 'driver.current_url', but in this way I am redirected to a new URL. I do not want the redirection since I have more things to do on the current page and want to stay on the same page. I can not use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> to open the new page in a new tab, either.

#### My idea

I read about how to find the source Javascript code ([How to find what code is run by a button or element in Chrome using Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23472334/how-to-find-what-code-is-run-by-a-button-or-element-in-chrome-using-developer-to)), but I found the codes too complex for me. Should I find the codes that produce the URL?

I wonder can I just "fork" the current page? Or something like simulating/executing the Javascript code in a separate sandbox? I am using python.

Comment: What's the page url?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus It is [this link](https://ke.wechess.cn/app/index.php?i=5&c=entry&m=xiangqi_lesson&do=search), I want to click the images and get the URLs they point to.

Comment: The way forward here (slow but reliable) would be: 1 - a loop to scroll the page down until there are no more new items loaded; 2 - get the image unique identifiers (the image urls would do here) and save them in a set; 3 - click on the first image, let it load, get your info,  save it, go back; scroll the page again, load the image lists, pop the image already visited, click on the next one; repeat until there are no more.

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Thank you for the comments. In fact, I want to avoid scrolling the page repeatedly. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm sure it must be, however it would go against the minimal complexity budget principle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. The idea is to modify the javascript codes.

##### Step 1: locate the javascript codes that cause the redirection.

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12419326/9758790). Note that for me I also add Event Listener Breakpoints for the load event.

##### Step 2: modify the javascript codes and delete redirection

Just find the line where the new URL has been computed and is being directed to. Store the url in a global javascript variable `target_url`.

##### Step 3: Use an extension to do the modification automatically in Selenium

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77251290/9758790). In a word, use the extension *Resource Override*.

##### Step 4: Selenium side, get the variable `url`

`my_target_url = driver.execute_script("return target_url;")`

Answer (score 0):

You can hash the target element first. When refreshed (if have to), retrieve all elements again and find the one with the hash you got at the beginning. A workaround though not perfect.